# Can I change the default behavior of the 'execute' command in the SSMS UI, for stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server

When I want to execute a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, I just right-click on the stored procedure name, select 'Execute Stored Procedure...' and the below script is generated:

```
USE [AnimalProductsCoSD]
GO
DECLARE @return_value int       

EXEC    @return_value = [CoSD].[BusinessLogic]
    @BusinessToolID = N'all rules'      

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
 GO
```

My question is...
How can I by default also have the generated script include:

```
exec CosD.BusinessLogicUtil
```

Comment: You can't.  SSMS is coded to generate an exec statement for only the selected item using the process you mention.

Comment: Agreed with @squillman. If you want to also execute another stored procedure at the same time, consider looking into having your initial stored procedure execute the subsequent one/s.

Comment: ok ok thanks so much